# Is there a way to perform a cross join or Cartesian product in excel?

Tags: sql, database, excel, join, cross-join

At the moment, I cannot use a typical database so am using excel temporarily.  Any ideas?

The [image]

Comment: One second, the formatting is butchered in this post.

Comment: Check this article http://www.nullskull.com/q/10113257/need-a-cross-join-of-the-rows-from-two-excel-sheets.aspx

Answer (score 13):

You have 3 dimensions here: dim1 (ABC), dim2 (123), dim3 (XYZ).

Here is how you make a cartesian product of 2 dimensions using standard Excel and no VBA:

1) Plot dim1 vertically and dim2 horizontally. Concatenate dimension members on the intersections:

[image: Step 1 - plotting dimensions]

2) Unpivoting data. Launch pivot table wizard using ALT-D-P (don't hold ALT, press it once). Pick "Multiple consolidation ranges" --> create a single page.. --> Select all cells (including headers!) and add it to the list, press next.

[image: step2 - unpivoting data]

3) Plot the resulting **values** vertically and disassemble the concatenated strings

[image: step 3 - disassemble strings]

Voila, you've got the cross join. If you need another dimension added, repeat this algorithm again.

Cheers,

Constantine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very easy way to generate the Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of lists using Pivot tables:

https://chandoo.org/wp/generate-all-combinations-from-two-lists-excel/

The example is for two lists, but it works for any number of tables and/or columns.

Before creating the Pivot table, you need to [convert your value lists to tables](https://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using Excel formulas:

```
|    |       A        |       B        |       C        |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  1 |                |                |                |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  2 | Table1_Column1 | Table2_Column1 | Table2_Column2 |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  3 |       A        |       1        |       X        |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  4 |       B        |       2        |       Y        |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  5 |       C        |       3        |       Z        |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  6 |                |                |                |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  7 |      Col1      |      Col2      |      Col3      |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  8 |   = Formula1   |   = Formula2   |   = Formula3   |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  9 |   = Formula1   |   = Formula2   |   = Formula3   |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 10 |   = Formula1   |   = Formula2   |   = Formula3   |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 11 |      ...       |      ...       |      ...       |
| -- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |

Formula1: IF(ROW() >= 8 + (3*3*3), "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3 + MOD(FLOOR(ROW() - 8)/(3*3), 3), 1)))
Formula2: IF(ROW() >= 8 + (3*3*3), "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3 + MOD(FLOOR(ROW() - 8)/(3)  , 3), 2)))
Formula3: IF(ROW() >= 8 + (3*3*3), "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3 + MOD(FLOOR(ROW() - 8)/(1)  , 3), 3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## One* general formula to rule them all!

### The result

[image]

[image]

### The formula

```
MOD(CEILING.MATH([index]/PRODUCT([size of set 0]:[size of previous set]))-1,[size of current set])+1
```

This formula gives the index (ordered position) of each element in the set, where set `i` has a size of `n_i`. Thus if we have four sets the sizes would be [`n_1`,`n_2`,`n_3`,`n_4`].

Using that index one can just use the `index` function to pick whatever attribute from the set (imagine each set being a table with several columns one could use `index([table of the set],[this result],[column number of attribute])`.

### Explanation

The two main components of the formula explained, the cycling component and the partitioning component.

#### Cycling component

`=MOD([partitioning component]-1, [size of current set])+1`

- Cycles through all the possible values of the set.
- The [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) function is required so the result will "go around" the size of the set, and never "out of bounds" of the possible values.
- The `-1` and `+1` help us go from one-based  numbering (our set indexes) to [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)  numbering (for the modulo operation).

#### Partitioning component

`CEILING.MATH([index]/PRODUCT([size of set 0]:[size of previous set])`:

- Partitions the "cartesian index" in chunks giving each chunk an "name".
- The "cartesian index" is just a numbering from 1 to the number of elements in the Cartesian Product (given by the product of the sizes of each set).
- The "name" is just an increasing-by-chunk enumeration of the "cartesian index".
- To have the same "name" for all indexes belonging to each chunk, we divide the "cartesian index" by the number of partitions and "ceil" it (kind of round up) the result.
- The amount of partitions is the total size of the last cycle, since, for each previous result one requires to repeat it for each of this set's elements.
- It so happens that the size of the previous result is the product of all the previous sets sizes (including the size of a set before the first so we can generalize, which we will call the "set 0" and will have a constant size of 1).

### With screenshots

#### Set sizes

Prepared set sizes including the "Set0" one and the size of the Cartesian Product.

Here, the sizes of sets are:

- "Set0": 1 in cell `B2`
- "Set1": 2 in cell `C2`
- "Set2": 5 in cell `D2`
- "Set3": 3 in cell `E2`

Thus the size of the Cartesian product is 30 (`2*5*3`) in cell `A2`.

[image]

#### Results

Table structure `_tbl_CartesianProduct` with the following columns and their formulas:

- Results:

  - `Cartesian Index`: `=IF(ROW()-ROW(_tbl_CartesianProduct[[#Headers];[Cartesian Index]])<=$A$2;ROW()-ROW(_tbl_CartesianProduct[[#Headers];[Cartesian Index]]);NA())`
  - `concatenation`: `=TEXTJOIN("-";TRUE;_tbl_CartesianProduct[@[Index S1]:[Index S3]])`
  - `Index S1`: `=MOD(CEILING.MATH([@[Cartesian Index]]/PRODUCT($B$2:B$2))-1;C$2)+1`
  - `Index S2`: `=MOD(CEILING.MATH([@[Cartesian Index]]/PRODUCT($B$2:C$2))-1;D$2)+1`
  - `Index S3`: `=MOD(CEILING.MATH([@[Cartesian Index]]/PRODUCT($B$2:D$2))-1;E$2)+1`
- step "size of previous partition":

  - `Size prev part S1`: `=PRODUCT($B$2:B$2)`
  - `Size prev part S2`: `=PRODUCT($B$2:C$2)`
  - `Size prev part S3`: `=PRODUCT($B$2:D$2)`
- step "Chunk name":

  - `Chunk S1`: `=CEILING.MATH([@[Cartesian Index]]/[@[Size prev part S1]])`
  - `Chunk S2`: `=CEILING.MATH([@[Cartesian Index]]/[@[Size prev part S2]])`
  - `Chunk S3`: `=CEILING.MATH([@[Cartesian Index]]/[@[Size prev part S3]])`
- final step "Cycle through the set":

  - `Cycle chunk in S1`: `=MOD([@[Chunk S1]]-1;C$2)+1`
  - `Cycle chunk in S2`: `=MOD([@[Chunk S2]]-1;D$2)+1`
  - `Cycle chunk in S3`: `=MOD([@[Chunk S3]]-1;E$2)+1`

[image: Table structure for Cartesian product]

*: for the actual job of producing the Cartesian enumerations

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you can.  Here is a small example:

```
Sub SqlSelectExample()
'list elements in col C not present in col B
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
           "DriverId=790;" & _
           "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "DefaultDir=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";ReadOnly=False;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "select ccc.test3 from [Sheet1$] ccc left join [Sheet1$] bbb on ccc.test3 = bbb.test2 where bbb.test2 is null  ", _
            con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    Range("g10").CopyFromRecordset rs   '-> returns values without match
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount          'get the # records
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit code in PowerQuery could solve the problem:

```
let
  Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbl_Data"]}[Content],
  AddColDim2 = Table.AddColumn(Quelle, "Dim2", each Quelle[Second_col]),
  ExpandDim2 = Table.ExpandListColumn(AddColDim2, "Dim2"),
  AddColDim3 = Table.AddColumn(ExpandDim2, "Dim3", each Quelle[Third_col]),
  ExpandDim3 = Table.ExpandListColumn(AddColDim3, "Dim3"),
  RemoveColumns = Table.SelectColumns(ExpandDim3,{"Dim1", "Dim2", "Dim3"})
in RemoveColumns
```

[image]

Answer (score -6):

Try using a DAX `CROSS JOIN`. Read more at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/crossjoin-function-dax)

You can use the expression `CROSSJOIN(table1, table2)` to create a cartesian product.