# Concatenate multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If column A contains

```
blue
red
green
yellow
```

and column B contains

```
fish
dog
cat
horse
```

what would be a formula to put the following in column C?

```
bluefish
bluedog
bluecat
bluehorse
redfish
reddog
redcat
redhorse
greenfish
greendog
greencat
greenhorse
yellowfish
yellowdog
yellowcat
yellowhorse
```

I looked at using a PivotTable, but it didn't work using columns from different sheets in the document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to perform a cross join or Cartesian product in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999604/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-cross-join-or-cartesian-product-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with native Excel formula then try below approach

**Assumption:**
Data in cells `A1:A4` and `B1:B4` respectively and formula being written in cell `C1`.

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,CEILING(ROW()/4,1))&INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MOD(ROW()-1,4)+1)`

Copy down as much as needed.

**Note:** Depending on your actual layout some of the parameters will need adjustments.

**Edit**

In cell `D1` insert formula `=MATCH("zz",A:A,1)`.

In cell `D2` insert formula `=MATCH("zz",B:B,1)`

In cell `C1` insert following formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$D$1),CEILING(ROW()/4,1))&INDEX($B$1:INDEX(B:B,$D$2),MOD(ROW()-1,4)+1),"")`

Copy up to maximum number of rows you expect the combinations to occur.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with an unknown number of cells in each column? We are trying to make a reusable template.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the help of @shrivallabha.redij. Here's the formula that worked for me:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$D$1),CEILING(ROW()/$D$2,1))&INDEX($B$1:INDEX(B:B,$D$2),MOD(ROW()-1,$D$2)+1),"")`

The difference was using the value of `$D$2` for the row calculation.